# How to create deep copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have this code, and I have to create a copy constructor for it to create a deep copy of the passed object. How can I create that?

```
template<typename T>
class SSL {
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head = nullptr;
public:
    // ...
};
```

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you really want to copy a node, including the pointer?  You'll have two objects with the same pointer (i..e. two data with links pointing to the same next node).

Comment: For linked list structures, you'll have to make new copies of the nodes and re-link them, so that the copied nodes are independent of the original nodes.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` everywhere instead of `Node*` to help make destruction automatic. This will also make the implicitly-defined move operations well-formed and correct, leaving only the copy operations for you to implement.

Comment: I think T must be the same type for all nodes in one SLL object. So why don't using a STL container for multiple elements of the same type?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to iterate the source object's list, making new nodes that have copies of its data, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class SSL {
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next = nullptr;
        Node(const T &value) : data(value) {}
    };

    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    // ...

    SSL() = default;

    SSL(const SSL &src) {
        Node **n = &head;
        for (Node *cur = src.head; cur; cur = cur->next) {
            *n = new Node{cur->data};
            n = &(n->next);
        }
    }

    SSL(SSL &&src) : head(src.head) {
        src.head = nullptr;
    };

    ~SSL() {
        Node *cur = head;
        while (cur) {
            Node *n = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
            delete n;
        }
    }

    SSL& operator=(SSL rhs) {
        std::swap(head, rhs.head);
        return *this;
    }

    // ...
};
```